# String Increment in a given base

Tags: java, string

I got this question:

> Increase v value by 1 in given targetBase. For example
>   increment(“1044”, 5) should return “1100”. In the above case, ‘4’+1 =
>   ‘5’ which is NOT a valid symbol in base 5. In such a situation, set
>   the current character to ‘0’ and increase the character before it.
>   Repeat until you find a character that can be increased within the
>   target base system.

So far in my understanding it should change the last value if it's higher than 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. 
So far I have in my code:

```
 public static String increase(String v, int targetBase)
  for (int i = value.length(); i<0; i--) {
             if (v.charAt(i) == base - 1) {
                 v = value.replace(v.charAt(i), '0');
                 return v;
```

However I have no idea how to approach this question and which methods I should use. Can I get any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Tips: (a) You have `v`, not `value`. (b) When you do a backward loop, you start from `i = v.length() - 1` because the indexes are between `0` and `length()-1`, there is nothing at `v.length()`. The loop condition should be `i>=0`, not `i<0` as it never will be. (c) The character value is a digit, not the digit value. To get the value `5` from the character `'5'` you need to use `Character.digit(char,targetBase)`. (d) Read the instructions again carefully and try to do it with pen and paper first for various values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is not the way your professor wants you to solve it, but it can be done like this:

```
public static String increase(String v, int targetBase) {
    return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(v, targetBase) + 1, targetBase);
}
```

This parses the given `String` to an `int` in the given base, increment the result and converts it back to a `String` in the given base.

If you need to support bigger numbers, you can use `Long` instead of `Integer`:

```
public static String increase(String v, int targetBase) {
    return Long.toString(Long.parseLong(v, targetBase) + 1, targetBase);
}
```

And if you need to support arbitrary-precision numbers, just use `BigInteger`:

```
public static String increase(String v, int targetBase) {
    return new BigInteger(v, targetBase).add(BigInteger.ONE).toString(targetBase);
}
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I did test it with the AssertEquals that I have, it worked for all but gave errors for a particular:  assertEquals("9999999999999999", NumberSystemService.decrement("10000000000000000", 10));
Why does it do that?

Comment: What is `NumberSystemService.decrement`?

Comment: Oh Whoops grabbed the value from the wrong test (since they have identical numbers for the test) 
  assertEquals("10000000000000000", NumberSystemService.increase("9999999999999999", 10));

Comment: 10000000000000000: this is not an `int` anymore so that's why it fails. I edited my post to support long values.

Comment: @Tunaki I think the professor was clever enough to put tests in that would defeat this strategy. :-)

Comment: @RealSkeptic `BigInteger` would still defeat the clever professor :)!

Comment: @Tunaki Hahaha the new methods worked you sly genius